# Forward email with a table in the body

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm really new to using vba in Outlook.

I was wondering if there is a way to write a script which can do the following
When run, it can forward the email to a particular address and put a blank table in the body with 4 rows and 4 columns

any help will be much appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Hi & welcome to Stack Overflow, you're generally expected to show some effort towards solving the problem, and "I'm really new" is usually code-word for "I don't know jack, please give me the answer", which is really bad form, and also against the etiquette here.  You're expected to have a basic understanding of your problem (at least) and also to provide code that you've attempted and if possible, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explanation of your specific problem or error.

Comment: If you don't know how to do something, please first [google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=outlook+vba+insert+table&oq=Outlook+VBA+add+Table&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.4744j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and then if you get stuck or have errors with your code, that is a good time to ask questions for assistance and troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

*Work with **[Tables.Add Method (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845710.aspx)** which Returns a Table object that represents a new, blank table added to a document.*

*Make sure the Email is HTML format*

*Syntax*

```
expression .Add(Range, NumRows, NumColumns, DefaultTableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior)
```

*Your Outlook Code Example would be*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim Item As Outlook.mailitem
    Dim Forward As Outlook.mailitem
    Dim Recip As Recipient
    Dim Inspector As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim Selection As Word.Selection
    
'   // Select the Item you would like to forward    
    Set Item = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    Set Forward = Item.Forward
    Set Recip = Forward.Recipients.Add("0m3r@Email.com")
        Recip.Type = olTo
        Forward.Display
        
    Set Inspector = Application.ActiveInspector()
    Set wdDoc = Inspector.WordEditor
    Set Selection = wdDoc.Application.Selection
    
        Selection.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, _
                             NumRows:=4, NumColumns:=4, _
                             DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, _
                             AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed
    
    
'        // Uncomment to send
'        Forward.Sent
        
    Set Inspector = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set Selection = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

*Email Body Example*

[image]

---

***[Remember to add reference to word xx object library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264402.aspx)***

> *1. From the Tools menu, choose References to display the References dialog box.*
>
> *2. The References dialog box shows all object libraries registered with the   operating system. Scroll through the list for the application whose object library you want to reference. If the application isn't listed, you can use the Browse button to search for object libraries (*.olb and *.tlb) or executable files (*.exe and *.dll on Windows). References whose check boxes are checked are used by your project; those that aren't checked are not used, but can be added.*

Comment: In order to refrence do i go to tools in word?

Comment: @alli No, you go to Tools > References in the Visual Basic window from Outlook.